# I need help joining two queries to get one table as result

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I need help joining two queries I'm using to get the result in one query instead of two different

The first query is:

```
SELECT p.ID as product_id, p.post_title,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_gender' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as gender, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as price, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_color' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as color, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_category' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as category,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_size' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as size
FROM    
  wp_posts p 
  join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id 
group by 
  p.ID
```

The second one is:

```
SELECT parentmeta.post_id as post_id,
 concat((select option_value from wp_options where option_name ='siteurl'  limit 1),'/wp-content/uploads/',childmeta.meta_value)                           as url
 FROM wp_postmeta childmeta 
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childmeta.post_id=parentmeta.meta_value)
 WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and childmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
 AND parentmeta.post_id = p.ID  //I want to used the same ID as the previous query
```

Now both tables give me this result

First query:

```
product_id  post_title   gender    price   color   category   size
83          Puma-Tshirt  Man       19      RED     Tshirt     Medium
86          Nike-Pants   Man       49      BLACK   Pants      Medium
```

Second query:

```
product_id   url
83           www.img.com/puma.jpg
86           www.img.com/nike.jpg
```

What I want is to combine the queries to get something like:

```
product_id  post_title   gender    price   color   category   size   url
83          Puma-Tshirt  Man       19      RED     Tshirt     Medium www.img.com/puma.jpg
86          Nike-Pants   Man       49      BLACK   Pants      Medium www.img.com/nike.jpg
```

All help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the two query

```
select t1.*, t2.* 
from  (
  SELECT p.ID as product_id, p.post_title,
         max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_gender' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as gender, 
         max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as price, 
         max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_color' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as color, 
         max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_category' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as category,
         max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_size' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as size
  FROM wp_posts p 
  join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id 
  group by  p.ID 
) t1 
inner join  (
  SELECT parentmeta.post_id as post_id,
   concat((select option_value from wp_options where option_name ='siteurl'  limit 1),'/wp-content/uploads/',childmeta.meta_value)                           as url
   FROM wp_postmeta childmeta 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childmeta.post_id=parentmeta.meta_value)
   WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and childmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
) t2 on t1.product_id = t2.post_id
```

Comment: In the second last line, AND parentmeta.post_id = p.ID => p.ID is unkown, that's the main problem of me trying to combine these two

Comment: @AbdelKdj   .. i see you have rremoved  your comment  for accepting answer  .. ............

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to, I thought you could put two answers as accepting answer. I put it back to yours. Sorry again

Answer (score 2):

```
( SELECT p.ID as product_id, p.post_title,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_gender' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as gender, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as price, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_color' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as color, 
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_category' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as category,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_size' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as size
FROM    
  wp_posts p 
  join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id 
group by 
  p.ID )   
UNION   
(SELECT parentmeta.post_id as post_id,
 concat((select option_value from wp_options where option_name ='siteurl'  limit 1),'/wp-content/uploads/',childmeta.meta_value)                           as url
 FROM wp_postmeta childmeta 
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childmeta.post_id=parentmeta.meta_value)
 WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and childmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
 AND parentmeta.post_id = p.ID  //I want to used the same ID as the previous query)
```

This will give you the required result.
From your question it is like you just want combination of this two irrespective of their joins and all.

Comment: @iamrasjhah thanks for the fast reply, but I still dont know how to work with the ID in the second query it gives me : #1054 - Unknown column 'p.ID' in 'where clause'

Comment: You can try the answer told by @scaisEdge as it makes sense if you want the same ID

Answer (score 1):

Query structure will be-

```
SELECT 
A.*,B.Url
FROM
(
    --Your First Query
)A
INNER JOIN 
(
    --Your Second Query
)B
ON A.Product_id = B.Product_id
```

Note: Use LEFT JOIN if possibilities are there to have less records in Query 2 compare to Query 1.